# Query across partitions in partitioned table in BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I got a BigQuery table partitioned on a daily basis and i need to return the average of a columns for all the partition that belongs to a month. In other words, my desired output would have a column for year-month and a column with the average of the values of the same columns over a month: `|year-month|avg_value|`. A group_by partition, if you want.

I managed to to access those informations for a single partition, e.g. for february 2023:

```
SELECT *
FROM `name_of_the_table`
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE(_PARTITIONTIME))= 2023 
AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE(_PARTITIONTIME)) = 02
)
```

and by looping over this query i can reach my desired output, but i look forward to learn a smarter solution.

I also have managed to access the partition infos:

```
SELECT table_name, partition_id, total_rows
FROM `dataset_name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS`
WHERE partition_id IS NOT NULL
and table_name = 'table_name'
order by partition_id desc
```

but have no clues on how to merge those infos. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for a group by.

```
SELECT
  FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y%m", _PARTITIONTIME) year_month,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  `table`
GROUP BY
  1
ORDER BY
  1 DESC
```

Comment: Sounds like you are right! Thank you!